# Rails Form for creating multiple entries of same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new to rails and I am struggling to design a form. I have model and a controller for "User". I have created a form which accepts one user at a time. What I am trying to create is a form to accept multiple user from the same page.

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Form in new

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</fieldset>
```

Note: I know how to create [Nested form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). If you see the link the tutorial shows how to create multiple questions for a survey. What I want is to create multiple surveys in the same form.

Comment: by multiple users, do you mean exact number or number should be dynamic?

Comment: If `User` belongs_to any other Model, you can create a form for that Model, and nest multiple users.

Comment: Number will be dynamic i.e it will depend upon the count of other model present

Comment: @Santosh User doesn't belong to any other Model. I want a standalone form for user which will facilitate creation of multiple users at one time.

Answer (score 1):

try to do something like:

```
<%= form_tag(some_url_path, method: :put) do %>
    <% for user in @users %>  
        <%= fields_for "users[]", user do |f| %>  
            <%= render 'fields', f: f, user: user %>
        <% end %>  
    <% end %>  
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and in controller you should create `@users` instead of one single `@user` in `new` method, and in `create` method to accept multiple users instead one.

UPDATE:

when you want to update your users in controller, you can do like (I didn't test it):

```
User.update(params[:users].keys, params[:users].values)
```

and to create:

```
User.create(params[:users].values)
```

`params[:users].keys` should be hash of user ids and `params[:users].values` should be hash of attributes of corresponding users

I don't know how you plan to manage of dynamic number of users, but maybe this could help.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using a similar approach(using form_tag) but I am still not sure this is the best way to go since it created complications with strong params in rails 4. So keeping it open for any future answers.

Comment: yes sure, definitely should be changed `params[:users]` and used strong params. I've just wanted to show example how it could be solved